# mysql client connection gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I have installed gcloud client library but GCP keeps on giving me this error what could the issue

ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) Mysql client not found.  Please install a mysql client and make sure it is in PATH to be able to connect to the database instance

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that either you have not installed the MySQL client locally, or gcloud can't find it.

If you have not installed MySQL yet, [follow the instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/#mysql-getting-started-installing) to do so.

If you have installed MySQL but you're still getting this error, try entering `mysql` at the shell prompt.  If you get a `command not found` error, MySQL is missing from your $PATH, and you need to figure out where it has been installed.

For example, on OS X, MySQL is by default installed in the directory `/usr/local/mysql/bin/`.  Add this to your $PATH, and it should start working:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

We get this error when mysql client is not installed in your machine.

1. Refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM4aZJW_Ojs&t=150s&ab_channel=AmitThinks video to install my-sql in windows.
2. Post installation of my-sql add the path `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` to `PATH` environment variable.
3. Close and then open your Google Cloud SDK shell and run the command again.

This will solve the problem.