# ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) Mysql client not found

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Note there is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429326/mysql-client-connection-gcloud) but not fixing my issue:

I had wamp server which comes with mysql server, the path is there. I installed SDK, able to connect to it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud beta sql connect welynxmysql --user=root
```

However in Cloud Shell, it throws out an error complaining below:

> You need the [cloud_sql_proxy] component to use the `sql connect`
> command. ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect)  The cloud_sql_proxy
> component(s) is unavailable through the packaging system  you are
> currently using. Please consider using a separate installation  of the
> Cloud SDK created through the default mechanism described at:
>
> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

What am I missing here? How can I connect to mysql instance/database in Cloud Shell?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The answer depends on  how you have configured Cloud SQL and which tools you want to use. From the error message, you need to install and configure Cloud SQL Proxy or (not recommended) whitelist all IP addresses. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here? How can I connect to mysql instance/database in Cloud Shell?

If you are not able to connect to your Cloud SQL instance, you could try to either follow:

- [Quickstart for Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart)
- [Quickstart for using the proxy for local testing](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test)

You could also try to [reset your Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell#resetting) (note: this will delete all your files within Cloud Shell) as stated [here:](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell#resetting)

> **Important: This will permanently delete all files in your home directory.**

Then, you could try to do a fresh installation of the [Google Cloud's SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install).

If none of those works for you, you could try to authorize your account again within the Cloud Shell as follows:

Before beginning, make sure that your Cloud Shell is using your project. If you are not sure you could also run this command to set your project:

```
gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]
```

Where `PROJECT_ID` is the project ID where the Cloud SQL instance is located. Then:

1. Go to your Cloud Shell and run this command (please notice the `sudo` at
   the beginning):

   `sudo gcloud auth login`
2. Click on the link displayed on the Cloud Shell and log in with your
   Google account.
3. Copy the code displayed on your screen.
4. Switch to the Cloud Shell, paste it there and hit enter.
5. You can now run the command as follows:

   `gcloud beta sql connect [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]`

or:

```
gcloud sql connect [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]
```

Where `YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME` is the name of your Cloud SQL instance.

I hope it helps.